# How to reverse a string without using a temp string and C lib?

Tags: c

I'm trying to reverse a string without using a temp string, but when I execute the program I have `olllo` as result not `olleH`.

Here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <string.h> 

    int main(){
        char *str = strdup("Hello");
        int reverse(char * str){
            int i=0;
            int j = strlen(str)-1;
            while(i<=j){
                (str[i]) = (str[j]);
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        return 0;
        } 
        reverse(str);
        printf("string = %s\n", str);
        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: This is not C. You cannot nest function definitions in C.

Comment: @rightføld: He may be using gcc's extension which allow it.

Comment: It's not dupulicated, i'm trying to create a function that reverses a string without using a temp string. I didn't find an exemple like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do such thing since your `char *str` is a kind of constant variable : you've just put something in it without using any dynamic memory allocation function like `malloc()`. You cannot modify this pointer's content unless you duplicate it.

Use `strdup(char *)` like this :

```
char * str = strdup("Hello");
```

Then you'll be able to modify your strings content.

Comment: I've tried this but i have olllo as result and not olleH

Comment: @JamesH Now that the segmentation fault is resolved, I suggest asking a new question.

Comment: Now the problem is in your algorithm. When you swap your characters, you never store the previous value of str[i] in a tmp_char, you just lose it.